# FME SnappingFactory's "distance" parameter

Tags: c#-4.0, data-transfer

I'm busy on developping a data transform tool based on `FME` and I'm confused with the **distance** parameter of the `SnappingFactory`, I want to know the unit of it.It is simply describled in the official manual that the distance is in ground units.However, i don't
know what that means.

Looking forward someone to give an explicit explanation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SnappingFactory uses the same Unit as the Coordinate System the data you process is in. E.g.:If your data is in EPSG:4326 the unit is meter.